# permissions of a proxy model in a new app not well created?

Tags: django

The permissions of my proxy Model of a User Model are not well created.

In my "customers" app, I have:

models.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True
        app_label = 'customers'
        verbose_name = 'Customer account'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Customer accounts'
```

admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomerAdmin(UserAdmin):

   def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.exclude(Q(is_staff=True) | Q(is_superuser=True))
        return qs

admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
```

When I look at the permissions table, I see that the created permissions for my proxy Model are related to the User Content Type and not the Content Type of my proxy Model.
I then have in the admin permissions like that:

auth | Customer account | Can add Customer account

instead of:

customers | Customer account | Can add Customer account

I manually changed the content type of the permissions on the database and it worked but why is it not created the way I was expecting? Is that a bug or am I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was a known bug in Django. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154. It's reported as fixed in version 2.2.

For earlier versions, you can either insert them yourself or use a post_syncdb handler, if you run into this again.